# Lightswitch in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-lightswitch

Can I host a Lightswitch application inside of ASP.NET MVC?

Thanks

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer: The LightSwitch presentation tier is a Silverlight application; it can run as a Windows desktop application or hosted in a browser. ASP.NET MVC can host a silverlight control.... BTW, could you explain why you want to do this?

Comment: I am looking at embedding forms into my app, just considered the latest options...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it *may* be technically possible, if it's just something you're just "thinking about doing", I wouldn't advise it. If it was something that you really *had to do*, then you may find a way to do it, but you'd need to ask yourself, "do I really want to go to all the trouble to figure this out"?

It's not the way that LS was intended to be used.